# Running Initialization Script After Setting Up Aurora Serverless Cluster v2 Using Terraform

Tags: terraform, mysql-cluster, amazon-rds-aurora

We have successfully created an Aurora Serverless Cluster v2 using the terraform-aws-rds-aurora Terraform module. Now, we want to run an initialization script after the cluster setup to create databases and grant privileges to a user. The script is as follows:

```
-- Create databases
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db1;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db2;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db3;

-- Create user and grant permissions
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'userpass';

-- Grant permissions on db1
GRANT CREATE, ALTER, DROP, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT, REFERENCES, RELOAD, INDEX, LOCK TABLES ON db1.* TO 'user'@'localhost';

-- Grant permissions on db2
GRANT CREATE, ALTER, DROP, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT, REFERENCES, RELOAD, INDEX, LOCK TABLES ON db2.* TO 'user'@'localhost';

-- Grant permissions on db3
GRANT CREATE, ALTER, DROP, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT, REFERENCES, RELOAD, INDEX, LOCK TABLES ON db3.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

How can we integrate the execution of this initialization script into our Terraform code, specifically after the Aurora Serverless Cluster v2 has been set up? Are there any Terraform resources or modules that can help achieve this?